# F# Update Variable in Pipe

Tags: f#, pipe

Is it possible to update the parameter of a pipe execution flow? 
The addedBalance function is the function that is calling the updateBalance and getBalance functions on the account. I cannot update this part of the code and it's in a different module.

```
let account = mkBankAccount() |> openAccount
let openingBalance = account |> getBalance 

let addedBalance = 
    account 
    |> updateBalance 10.0m
    |> getBalance
```

How can I update the account variable so that the updated balance will be safed?
The approach that I'm currently using is not updating the balance permanently:

```
let updateBalance change account = {balance = account.balance + change ; accStatus = account.accStatus}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, one way to do ti is to add account as a parameter so that

```
let addedBalance acct = 
    acct 
    |> updateBalance 10.0m
    |> getBalance
```

Don't forget F# is immutable by default, this would probably mean you need to change how you think about "upating account" , really you will have a new instance of `account`

Comment: Sry, I missed the inofrmation that I cannot update this part of the code. 
So the pipe operator creates a new instance of the account variable?

Comment: no, I think you might need to read this https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/thinking-functionally-intro/ (as in the whole series of posts not just the first one)